# Update the perl script to include number of times the row is repeated

Tags: perl, duplicates

I have below a perl script which gives a list of entries which are present more than once in a file/STDIN. 
I want to update this script so that it also shows how many times the entries have been repeated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %duplicates;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  $duplicates{$_}++;
}

foreach my $key (keys %duplicates) { 
  if ($duplicates{$key} > 1) {
    delete $duplicates{$key}; 
    print "$key\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print `$duplicates{$key}` while iterating on keys:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %duplicates;

while (<>) {
  chomp; 
  $duplicates{$_}++;
}

foreach my $key (keys %duplicates) { 
  if ($duplicates{$key} > 1) {
       print "$key is repeated $duplicates{$key} times\n";
       delete $duplicates{$key}; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks MarcoS, this was what I wanted. Kiitos!

Answer (score 4):

The [`delete`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/delete.html) builtin returns the value deleted. So you can use:

```
print "$key: ", delete $duplicates{$key}, "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `print $duplicates{$key}`. Or am I missing something?

Also, are you sure you need to `delete $duplicates{$key}`?